# Copying text from cell above a blank until it reaches a cell with text

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with 67k lines of data that is a QB report. There are customers listed and a blank line next to each purchase and then a Total line for each customer.

I need to fill in the blank lines with that customer's name. I have been dragging the names down one by one, but after 3 days, I'm only on row 7933.

I tried using the VLookup for a separate spreadsheet that holds 25k email addresses.  That worked for getting email addresses for customers that had them, but it doesn't work when the customer isn't on that list and/or didn't have an email address.

Comment: Which columns are the names and totals in ?

Comment: you'd better add a screenshot of your data layout

Comment: Load your table into Power Query (`Get Data From Table or Range`); Select the relevant column, and `Fill Down`. Then Close and Load back to the workbook.

Answer (score 1):

- Select all data rows in the column
- Select all blank cells: <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd> to open "Go to" dialog> <kbd>Special</kbd> > <kbd>Blanks</kbd> > <kbd>OK</kbd>
- Input a formula `=A2`, press <kbd>Ctrl+Enter</kbd> to apply formula for all blank cells
- (Optional) Covert formulas to values, select data rows as the first step, Copy > Paste Values

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Find and select cells that meet specific conditions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-and-select-cells-that-meet-specific-conditions-2d686424-6150-4015-a8e4-a5990f4d7e3a?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&ns=excel&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zxl900&helpid=20971&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

[image]

---

VBA is an option too.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, sVal As String
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range
    Set rngData = Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    arrData = rngData.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        If Len(arrData(i, 1)) > 0 Then
            sVal = arrData(i, 1)
        Else
            arrData(i, 1) = sVal
        End If
    Next i
    rngData.Value = arrData
End Sub
```

Comment: The names were only in column A.  Thank all of you for your help.  This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Should data layout be the one as in @taller's answer, you may also use

```
Sub DoIt()
    With Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
            .Formula = "=R[-1]C"
        End With
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Without VBA:
Insert a Column next to the names.
Assuming the customer name is in column A and you have at least one header row, put the following formula into the new column B:

```
=IF(A2<>"",A2,B1)
```

Copy this formula down.

Now you can either hide column A, or you can use Copy + PasteSpecial(Values) to make the names permanent - after that you can delete column A

Hint: Make a copy of your workbook before you try that...